# Is there a way to analyze the http router from URLs?

Tags: http, nginx

While we use some frameworks (like Koa in Node.js) to start a web server, there is a router table shows you the pattern like:

```
router
  .get('/', func...)
  .post('/users', func...)
  .put('/users/:id', func...)
  .del('/users/:id', func...);
```

Or flask in python:

```
@app.route('/a')
def func
   # ...

@app.route('/b')
def func
   # ...

@app.route('/c')
def func
   # ...
```

With those pattern, you can match the URL to certain function. But I wonder if there is way to analyze the router from URLs log (as for nginx log).
So that we can do a common non-intrusive router track.

Comment: You can use middlewares in node to log each url requests, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @PrabodhM Yeah, I know it. And it just print the url, but what I want is to get the router from URL log. Such as analyze some log like "/shop/df342casd" to aggregate a router like "/shop/:hash"